# Getting NoReverse match error upon passing context variable in {% url contextVariable %} in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

In my Django project, I am experiencing an where the revers url cannot be found. Basically I passed a context variable in the template's `{% url navLogoLinkName %}`, I checked from the source html code generated by the page that the navLogoLinkName generates the right link. When clicking on the link however, I get a NoReverseMatch error.

In my urls.py, you can see that I have a path with `name = 'hiddendimsum_nytorv'`

```
"""website URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls.conf import re_path
from index.views import indexPage, hdnytorv, hd2900, hdbynight
from takeawayWebshop.views import TakeawayWebshopMain
from webshopCart.views import AddRemoveCartItems
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.static import serve

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', indexPage.as_view()),
    path('hdnytorv', hdnytorv.as_view(), name='hiddendimsum_nytorv'),
    path('hd2900', hd2900.as_view(), name='hiddendimsum_2900'),
    path('hd2900_takeaway_webshop', TakeawayWebshopMain.as_view(), name="hiddendimsum_takeaway_webshop"),
    path('changeItemQuantityInBasket', AddRemoveCartItems.as_view()),
    #path('check-address-for-deliverable', AddressCheckForDeliverability.as_view()),
    #path('changeItemQuantityInBasket', ChangeItemQuantity.as_view()),
    #path('getTakeawayClosingOrderTime', lastPickupDeliveryOrderTime.as_view()),
    #path('isPriceAboveDeliveryLimit', totalPriceDeliveryPossible.as_view()),
    path('hdbynight', hdbynight.as_view(), name='hiddendimsum_bynight'),
    #path('takeawayCheckout', TakeawayCheckout.as_view()),
    #path('deliveryFormCheckout', DeliveryForm.as_view()),
    #path('pickupFormCheckout', PickUpForm.as_view()),
    #path('local_delivery_checkout_is_address_deliverable', localDeliveryCheckoutAddressCheck.as_view()),
    #path('process_pickup_or_delivery_form', deliveryPickupFormProcess.as_view()),
    #path('localDeliveryPayment', Payment.as_view(), name = 'localDeliveryPayment'),
    #path('getPaymentId', getPaymentId.as_view()),
    #path('paymentComplete', PaymentComplete.as_view(), name = 'paymentComplete'),
    #path('paymentNotification', paymentNotificationWebhook),
    #path('verifyPayment', paymentVerificationStaticPage.as_view(), name = 'verifyPayment'),
    #path('backendPaymentVerification', backendPaymentVerification.as_view()),
    re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), 
] 

#When in production medida url must always be added to urlpatterns
#if settings.DEBUG:
#urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In my template I have `href="{% url navLogoLinkName %}"` where navLogoLinkName is the context variable passed from the view.

```
{% load static %}
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-secondary" id ="navbar">
    <button class="navbar-toggler m-auto" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="#navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <a class="navbar-brand navbar-left" href="{% url navLogoLinkName %}" id="navbarLogoLink">
        <img src="{{ navbarLogoPath }}" alt="{{ navbarLogoAlt }}" id="navbarLogo">
    </a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            {% for link in links %}
                {% if link.0 == 'BOOK TABLE' %}
                <li class="nav-item active" id="navbarListItem">
                    <a class="nav-link px-6" id ="mainNavlink" href="{{ link.1 }}" target="_blank"><h3 id="linkText">{{ link.0 }}</h3></a>
                </li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="nav-item active" id="navbarListItem">
                        <a class="nav-link px-6" id ="mainNavlink" href="{{ link.1 }}"><h3 id="linkText">{{ link.0 }}</h3></a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% if controlReport %}
            {% autoescape off %}
                <a class="pull-right" href={{controlReport}} target="_blank">
                    <img src={% static 'media/kontrolRapport.gif' %} width="15%" height = auto> 
                </a>
            {% endautoescape %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</nav>
```

In views.py I have `context['navLogoLinkName'] = 'hiddendimsum_nytorv'`. From urls.py, you can see that hiddendimsum_nytorv should point to `hdnytorv` in path.

```
from webshopCart.models import CartItem
from .models import TakeawayWebshop
from restaurant.models import Restaurant
# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from django.conf import settings
from website.Modules.webshopUtils import Session, getTotalItemsInCart

webshopName = 'Hidden Dimsum 2900'
class TakeawayWebshopMain(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = dict()
        context['navbarLogoPath'] = 'static/media/hd2900coverLogo.png'
        context['navLogoLinkName'] = 'hiddendimsum_nytorv'
        context['links'] = list()
        context['aboutUsRestaurant'] = Restaurant.objects.filter(name = webshopName)[0] 

        #Import the webshop object followed by the products
        webshop = TakeawayWebshop.objects.filter(name = webshopName)
        webshop = webshop[0]
        products = webshop.getProducts()

        #Check if session exists
        session = Session(request = request)
        isSessionValid = session.isSessionValid(webshopModelObject = webshop)
        context['sessionValidity'] = isSessionValid
        
        #Get product quantity if session exists
        productToDisplay = list()
        for product in products:
            productDict = dict()
            productDict['product'] = product
            if isSessionValid:
                cartItem = CartItem.objects.filter(session_id = request.session[settings.WEBSHOP_SESSION_KEY],
                product = product)

                if cartItem:
                    productDict['quantity'] = cartItem[0].quantity
                else:
                    productDict['quantity'] = 0
            else:
                productDict['quantity'] = 0
            productToDisplay.append(productDict)

        context['products'] = productToDisplay
        
        if isSessionValid:
            context['totalCartItems'] = getTotalItemsInCart(request = request)
        else:
            context['totalCartitems'] = 0
        
        print('from webshop main')
        print(context)

        return render(request, template_name="takeawayWebshopMain.html", context = context)
```

Below are the source html generated from the rendered page. You can see this snippet

```
<a class="navbar-brand navbar-left" href="/hdnytorv" id="navbarLogoLink">
            <img src="static/media/hd2900coverLogo.png" alt="" id="navbarLogo">
        </a>
```

which demonstrates that it is pointing to the correct link as in my urls.py.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Bootstrap css-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--social media icons-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=/static/landingPage.css>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=/static/takeawayWebshop.css>
    <title></title>

    <!--SEO-->
    <meta name="description" content="Hidden Dimsum 2900, Strandvejen 163, Hellerup online dimsum takeaway and local delivery webshop">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Hidden Dimsum 2900, dimsum takeaway webshop, dimsum local delivery, dumplings takeaway, online ordering">
    <meta name="author" content="Hidden Dimsum 2900"> 
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/static/media/favicon_hd32x32.png"/>
    
    <!--Font awesome-->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/efc09bd617.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--Google Analytics-->
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    
    
    <!--Easy table booking-->
    <!--Easy table booking embedded-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function() { var st=document.createElement('script'); st.type='text/javascript'; st.async=true; st.src='//book.easytablebooking.com/javascripts/widget/v2/book.js'; var sc=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; sc.parentNode.insertBefore(st, sc); })();
      </script>
      <noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
</head>

<body>
    
  
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-secondary" id ="navbar">
    <button class="navbar-toggler m-auto" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="#navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <a class="navbar-brand navbar-left" href="/hdnytorv" id="navbarLogoLink">
        <img src="static/media/hd2900coverLogo.png" alt="" id="navbarLogo">
    </a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            
        </ul>
        
    </div>
</nav>
    
  
<div class="container-fluid sticky-top" id="takeawayHeaderCartContainer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-11" id="cartIconContent">
            <a href="/takeawayCheckout">
                <i class="fa" id="shoppingCartIcon">&#xf07a;</i> <!--this code codes for the shopping cart icon-->
                <span class='badge badge-warning' id='lblCartCount'> 
                    
                    0 
                    
                </span>
            </a>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
  
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <h1 class="contentHeader">Menu</h1>
  <hr class = "titleHorisontalLine">
  <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-4">
      
        <div class="col-auto mt-5">
            <div class="card h-100 text-center">
              <div class="card-body">
                <!--Title -->
                <h5 class="card-title">Charr Siu Bao</h5>

                <!--Product image with link -->
                  <img class="card-img embed-responsive-item" src="/media/productImages/DimsumBox.jpg" alt="">
                
                <!--Product description-->
                <p class="card-text">some descriptions here</p>
                
                <!--Allergic note -->
                
                  <p class="card-text">allergy notes</p>
                

                <!--Price-->
                <h5 class="mt-4">100,- </h5>

                <div class="input-group">
                  
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary subtractItem" type="button" id="btn_subtract_charr-siu-bao" onclick="itemQuantityChangeButton(this)">
                      -
                    </button>
                  </div>
                
                  
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text_charr-siu-bao" placeholder="0" aria-label="ordered amount" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" readonly>
                  

                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary addOneItem" type="button" id="btn_add_charr-siu-bao" onclick="itemQuantityChangeButton(this)">
                      +
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      
        <div class="col-auto mt-5">
            <div class="card h-100 text-center">
              <div class="card-body">
                <!--Title -->
                <h5 class="card-title">Product A</h5>

                <!--Product image with link -->
                  <img class="card-img embed-responsive-item" src="/media/productImages/duckGaozi_TAI2jqx.jpg" alt="">
                
                <!--Product description-->
                <p class="card-text">product A description</p>
                
                <!--Allergic note -->
                

                <!--Price-->
                <h5 class="mt-4">100,- </h5>

                <div class="input-group">
                  
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary subtractItem" type="button" id="btn_subtract_product-a" onclick="itemQuantityChangeButton(this)">
                      -
                    </button>
                  </div>
                
                  
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text_product-a" placeholder="0" aria-label="ordered amount" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" readonly>
                  

                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary addOneItem" type="button" id="btn_add_product-a" onclick="itemQuantityChangeButton(this)">
                      +
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      
        <div class="col-auto mt-5">
            <div class="card h-100 text-center">
              <div class="card-body">
                <!--Title -->
                <h5 class="card-title">Product B</h5>

                <!--Product image with link -->
                  <img class="card-img embed-responsive-item" src="/media/productImages/duckGaozi_BcevHBI.jpg" alt="">
                
                <!--Product description-->
                <p class="card-text">product B description</p>
                
                <!--Allergic note -->
                

                <!--Price-->
                <h5 class="mt-4">200,- </h5>

                <div class="input-group">
                  
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary subtractItem" type="button" id="btn_subtract_product-b" onclick="itemQuantityChangeButton(this)">
                      -
                    </button>
                  </div>
                
                  
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text_product-b" placeholder="0" aria-label="ordered amount" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" readonly>
                  

                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary addOneItem" type="button" id="btn_add_product-b" onclick="itemQuantityChangeButton(this)">
                      +
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      
        <div class="col-auto mt-5">
            <div class="card h-100 text-center">
              <div class="card-body">
                <!--Title -->
                <h5 class="card-title">Product C</h5>

                <!--Product image with link -->
                  <img class="card-img embed-responsive-item" src="/media/productImages/porkGaozi_min_xa7mpZQ.jpg" alt="">
                
                <!--Product description-->
                <p class="card-text">Product C description</p>
                
                <!--Allergic note -->
                

                <!--Price-->
                <h5 class="mt-4">300,- </h5>

                <div class="input-group">
                  
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary subtractItem" type="button" id="btn_subtract_product-c" onclick="itemQuantityChangeButton(this)">
                      -
                    </button>
                  </div>
                
                  
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text_product-c" placeholder="0" aria-label="ordered amount" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" readonly>
                  

                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary addOneItem" type="button" id="btn_add_product-c" onclick="itemQuantityChangeButton(this)">
                      +
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      
        <div class="col-auto mt-5">
            <div class="card h-100 text-center">
              <div class="card-body">
                <!--Title -->
                <h5 class="card-title">pork gaozi</h5>

                <!--Product image with link -->
                  <img class="card-img embed-responsive-item" src="/media/productImages/porkGaozi.jpg" alt="">
                
                <!--Product description-->
                <p class="card-text">here is description for pork gaozi</p>
                
                <!--Allergic note -->
                

                <!--Price-->
                <h5 class="mt-4">50,- </h5>

                <div class="input-group">
                  
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary subtractItem" type="button" id="btn_subtract_pork-gaozi" onclick="itemQuantityChangeButton(this)">
                      -
                    </button>
                  </div>
                
                  
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text_pork-gaozi" placeholder="0" aria-label="ordered amount" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" readonly>
                  

                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary addOneItem" type="button" id="btn_add_pork-gaozi" onclick="itemQuantityChangeButton(this)">
                      +
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-end">
  <div class="row">
    <a href="/takeawayCheckout" role="button" id="checkoutLink">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Checkout</button>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
  
<footer class="bg-dark text-center text-white">
  <div class="container p-4 mx-auto">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Hiddendimsum2900" target="_blank" class="footerIcon">
      <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook fa-3x"></i>
    </a> 

    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/hiddendimsum2900" target="_blank" class="footerIcon">
      <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram fa-3x"></i>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="container p-2 mx-auto">
    <form method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="nVitBexkVreopuERtPpFqceQ7iImmDAyg6WLG8rqNj7dyZCuaZwwKsOfCf3EJSjo">
          <p><label for="newLetterEmailLabel" class="bodyText" id="newLetterEmailLabel">Newsletter Subscription</label></p>
          <input type="email" name="subscriptionEmail" placeholder="email@example.com">
          <button type="submit" name="action" class="btn btn-primary" value="emailSubscription" id="newsLetterSubmitButton">Subscribe</button>
          
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="text-center footerText p-3" id="footerAddress">
    ©Hidden Dimsum 2900
    <br>
    Strandvejen, 163, 2900, Hellerup
    <br>
    CVR: 38908901
    <br>
    Phone : +45-40388884
  </div>
</footer>
        

  <script src="/static/scripts/product_add_subtract_btn_clicked.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Still when clicking on the navbar logo image, I get the below error

```
Internal Server Error: /hdnytorv
...   
 django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '/' not found. '/' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
    [02/Apr/2022 23:46:16] "GET /hdnytorv HTTP/1.1" 500 209584
```

Comment: could you please post the complete error message. Your method is basically correct - the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: Also you can e.g. check if urlName ist correctly passed to the template by just printing it into html like "test{{ urlName }}test"

Comment: I have now updated it with the full error log. I checked by looking at the source html code and can confirm that the full urlName is passed correctly

Comment: The error message tells that navLogoLinkName is empty. So either you do not pass the context to the template in the view or there is a typo in the context definition.  Your idea to put a context variable in the url is ok. It is not necessary but it is possible. Depends what you need.

Comment: I have now presented the problem in full detail. The navLogoLinkName context variable is not empty. In the rendered page when I check the source code, I see the correct link. Still I get Noreverse match error. I suspect if it could be an issue with urls.py?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "[URL Namespaces](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces)". Add an "app-name" in your urls.py:

```
app_name = 'myAppName'
...
path('hd2900', hd2900.as_view(), name='hd2900')
...
```

And in your template, use `{% url 'myAppName:hd2900' %}`:

```
<a class="navbar-brand navbar-left" href="{% url 'myAppName:hd2900' %}" id="navbarLogoLink">
   <img src="{{ navbarLogoPath }}" alt="{{ navbarLogoAlt }}" id="navbarLogo">
</a>
```

Comment: If I do this, I receive an error NoReverseMatch at /hdnytorv
'takeawayWebshopApp' is not a registered namespace. Also even if this solution works, will it allow parsing the variable using context from views.py?